# Extract xyz values from list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I want to extract values from a list of (named) lists in R.

**Example**

The data looks as follows:

```
data <- list('1' = list(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,3,4), z = c(2,3,7)), 
                '2' = list(x = c(2,3,4,5), y = c(3,4,5,6), z = c(1,2,3,5)))
```

From a specified list (e.g., `'1'`), I would like to extract all the first/second/etc elements from the lists. The choice for the index of the element should be random.

For example, if I want to sample from the first list (i.e., `'1'`), I generate a random index and extract the x, y, and z values corresponding to that random index. Say the index is 2, then the elements should be `x=2`, `y=3`, and `z=3`.

**Approach**

I thought a function should be able to do the job. The first step was to call the list from the function:

This works:

```
x <- function(i){
    data$`1`
}
x(1)
```

But this doesn't:

```
x <- function(i){
        data$`i`
    }
    x(1)
```

**Question**

How do I call a list of named lists from within the function? And what is the most convenient way to sample data corresponding to the selected index?

Comment: 1) Use `data[[i]]` in your function. 2) Call that function like this `x("1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
get_elements <- function(data, i) {
  #select the main list
  tmp <- data[[i]]
  #Check the length of each sublist, select minimum value
  #and sample 1 number from 1 to that number
  rand_int <- sample(min(lengths(tmp)), 1)
  #select that element from each sub-list
  sapply(tmp, `[[`, rand_int)
}

get_elements(data, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly a solution would be with the "purrr" package:

```
library(purrr)
# list "name"
i <- '1'
# index
j <- 2

# to get the needed info as a list:
purrr::map(data[[i]], ~ .x[j])

# to get the needed info as a data.frame:
purrr::map_df(data[[i]], ~ .x[j])
```

Comment: Thanks, an elegant partial solution, but not (yet) entirely suitable for the problem. The length of the lists are different per ‘main’ list, therefore, I need a way to first check the length of the sublist, and then generate a random integer to sample from the list.

Comment: you can check the length with this statement: length(data[[i]])

Comment: or if you mean that the "sub-sub-lists" might have different lengths, than this would be an option to get the smallest: min(purrr::map_int(data[[i]], ~ length(.x)))