# Extract values from list of named lists in R

Tags: r, list, subset, sampling

Based on the names of sublists with xyz values of a list, I would like to extract a sample of the xyz values from a sublist. Note: the lists do not start at `1`.

**Example data**

```r
set.seed(123)

data <- list('4' = list(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5)),
             '5' = list(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5)),
             '6' = list(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5)),
             '7' = list(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5)),
             '8' = list(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5), z = rnorm(5)))
```

**Function to extract random values** (derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661618/extract-xyz-values-from-list-of-lists-in-r))

I have the following function to sample random xyz values from the list:

```r
get_elements <- function(data, i) {
  #select the main list
  tmp <- data[[i]]
  #Check the length of each sublist, select minimum value
  #and sample 1 number from 1 to that number
  rand_int <- sample(min(lengths(tmp)), 1)
  #select that element from each sub-list
  sapply(tmp, `[[`, rand_int)
}
```

**Example of function**

```r
# Show list number 8
data[['8']]
#> $x
#> [1]  0.3796395 -0.5023235 -0.3332074 -1.0185754 -1.0717912
#> $y
#> [1] 0.30352864 0.44820978 0.05300423 0.92226747 2.05008469
#> $z
#> [1] -0.4910312 -2.3091689  1.0057385 -0.7092008 -0.6880086

# Extract random combination from list 8
get_elements(data, '8')
#>           x           y           z 
#> -0.33320738  0.05300423  1.00573852
```

**Rewrite function**

Using the same function as above, I replaced `i` with `'i'`:

```r
get_elements <- function(data, i) {
  tmp <- data[['i']]                       # <-- changed i to 'i'
  rand_int <- sample(min(lengths(tmp)), 1)
  sapply(tmp, `[[`, rand_int)
}
```

**Error & Question**

```r
get_elements(data, 8)
```

> Warning in min(lengths(tmp)): no non-missing arguments to min;
> returning Inf list()

Suddenly the function breaks, and I do not understand why? What is the reason for this error?

Comment: With `data[['i']]` you are looking for an list entry called `i`.

Comment: Okay, but then I do not understand why it works to call: `data[['8']]`, but it doesn't work after rewriting the function? What specifically is going wrong there?

Comment: `data[['8']]` selects the entry named `8`. `i <- '8'; data[[i]]` also selects the entry named `8`. but here over `i`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So, essentially both should be the same, but how come that one ends up as error, while the other doesn't? To be more specific, I do understand the first part (up until Example function). But then I rewrite the function (change `i` to `'i'`) and the function breaks...

Comment: When you use `'i'` you are using the literal `i` and not the value stored in `i`.

Comment: Thanks, that is clear:)! Is there an easy way to call the function like `get_elements(data, 8)` and still end up with tmp <- data[['8']]?

Comment: Use: `data[[as.character(i)]]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get_elements <- function(data, i) 
{
  tmp <- data[[paste(i)]]
  rand_int <- sample(min(lengths(tmp)), 1)
  sapply(tmp, `[[`, rand_int)
}
```

The reason your initial code failed is because "i" is understood as "character i", not as "convert variable i into character". See:

```
i = 1
print("i") # i
print(i) # 1
```